# Histogram project: code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, histogram

This is the code I've isolated:

```
public static void randomIntArray(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt(-5, 15);
    }
    scoreHist(a);
}

public static void scoreHist(int[] scores) {
    int[] counts = new int[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        int index = scores[i];
        counts[index]++;
    }
}
```

But whenever I run this, it gives me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: (Insert Random # Here)
    at arrayhistogram.ArrayHistogram.scoreHist(ArrayHistogram.java:39)
    at arrayhistogram.ArrayHistogram.randomIntArray(ArrayHistogram.java:31)
    at arrayhistogram.ArrayHistogram.main(ArrayHistogram.java:21)
```

I'm lost with this. Ideas? I'm really stuck and have been going in circles with this for a while now.

Comment: +1 for isolating the problem.

Comment: what int value did you pass on function randomIntArray ? make sure its  not greater than the length of counts.  make sure you randomize positive values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
counts[index]
```

to

```
counts[index + 5]
```

This is because `index` comes from the `a` array whose elements are initialized to values between `-5` and `14` inclusive. However only values between `0` and `29` inclusive are allowed as indices to `counts`, hence you need to add `5`.

Comment: Also, there is room left for memory optimization: int[] counts = new int[20];

Answer (score 4):

```
int index = scores[i];
counts[index]++;
```

according to the randomInt (-5,15), it's possible the index can be negative.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the stuff that your code does :

You pick 'n' random numbers from -5 to 15 ( say n=5 ), push them into an array

Say, the array becomes

```
scores[] = {0,1,1,5,-3}
```

Now, you are passing this created array in the `scoreHist()`.

Now, see the state of variables during run time

```
   i       scores[i]        index               counts[index]
  ---      ---------        -----           ----------------------
//1st iteration
   0      scores[0]=0         0           counts[0]=counts[0]+1 -> 1       
Everything goes fine in the first iteration.
//2nd iteration
   1      scores[1]=1         1           counts[1]=counts[1]+1 -> 1
Everything goes fine here as well. Now "counts[] = {1,1}"
//3rd iteration
   2      scores[2]=1         1           counts[1]=counts[1]+1 -> 2
Things go alright. counts[1] has been updated. Now "counts[] = {1,2}"
//4th iteration
   3      scores[3]=5         5           counts[5]=counts[5]+1 -> 1
Things go absolutely fine here . 
//5th iteration
   4      scores[4]=-3        -3          counts[-3] !!!!!!!! It is out of bound limits for the       
                                                              array. This index does not exist.
```

This is what causes the exception that you have
Hope this helps.